# How to set iskeyword so it applies only when editing in the command line mode in vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I was trying to investigate to change the behavior of `<c-w>` in the command line mode in Vim, so that when I press that key when editing a path, it would only delete up to the last forward slash `/`.

To my surprise, `:help c_CTRL-W` says that behavior is determined by `iskeyword` option:

```
CTRL-W      Delete the |word| before the cursor.  This depends on the
        'iskeyword' option.
```

In my testing, I did observe CTRL-W in command line mode to change depending on the `iskeyword` option of the file I'm editing, which makes for an inconsistent experience when editing commands.

Does anyone know how to set `iskeyword` so that it only affects the command line mode?

Comment: vi/vim questions should be asked on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a command-line mapping for <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> that

- stores the current value of `iskeyword` in a variable: `:let g:iskeyword_old=&iskeyword`
- resets `iskeyword` to its default (or any other value): `:set iskeyword&`
- does <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> : `<C-W>`
- restores `iskeyword` from the variable: `:let &iskeyword=g:iskeyword_old`

Or, in the conciseness we all love about Vim:

```
:cnoremap <C-W> <Cmd>let g:iskeyword_old=&iskeyword<Bar>set iskeyword&<CR><C-W><Cmd>let &iskeyword=g:iskeyword_old<CR>
```

This way, <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> in the command line always uses the defaults of the `iskeyword` option. Everyone else can use theirs.